# Passing extra arguments to ggplot2 geoms: using ellipsis (...)

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a follow-up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57072096/passing-an-extra-parameter-to-a-custom-geom-in-ggplot2) question. I am trying to write my own geoms with custom parameters. My question is how to use ellipsis (...) to pass extra arguments.

The following example code works as expected:

```
draw_panel_func <- function(data, panel_params, coord, showpoints=FALSE) {
  print(showpoints)
  if(showpoints) {
    coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)
    grid::pointsGrob(coords$x, coords$y)
  } else {
    zeroGrob()
  } 
} 


## definition of the new geom. setup_data inserts the parameter 
## into data, therefore making it accessible for .draw_panel_func
GeomSimplePoint <- ggproto("GeomSimplePoint", Geom,
  required_aes = c("x", "y"),
  default_aes = aes(shape = 19, colour = "black"),
  draw_key = draw_key_point,
  extra_params = c("na.rm", "showpoints"),
  draw_panel = draw_panel_func
) 

geom_simple_point <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
                              position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                              inherit.aes = TRUE, showpoints=TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    geom = GeomSimplePoint, mapping = mapping,  data = data, stat = stat,
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, showpoints=showpoints, ...)
  )   
}
```

This works, and I can call

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_simple_point(showpoints=FALSE)
```

to omit the plotting of the points.

However, because I want to use a generic function for different new geoms, I would prefer to define the `draw_panel` function without explicitly naming the showpoints parameter, but using ellipsis. I tried the following (all the remainder of the code remains identical), it doesn't work:

```
draw_panel_func <- function(data, panel_params, coord, ...) {
  showpoints <- list(...)$showpoints
  if(showpoints) {
    coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)
    grid::pointsGrob(coords$x, coords$y)
  } else {
    zeroGrob()
  }
}
```

The error returned is:

> Error in if (showpoints) { : argument is of length zero

An interesting thing happens when I do the following:

```
draw_panel_func <- function(data, panel_params, coord, showpoints=FALSE, ...) {
  #showpoints <- list(...)$showpoints
  if(showpoints) {
    coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)
    grid::pointsGrob(coords$x, coords$y)
  } else {
    zeroGrob()
  }
}
```

For some reason, showpoints is now always FALSE. However, the `...` list is NULL. This is completely unexpected.

This is all very confusing and for certain it does not behave like I would expected. Is it possible to use ellipsis in this context? If yes, then how? What is happening here?

**EDIT:** Following the suggestion of Gilean0709 I tried to remove `showpoints` from the definition of `geom_simple_point`:

```
geom_simple_point <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
                              position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                              inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    geom = GeomSimplePoint, mapping = mapping,  data = data, stat = stat,
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )   
}
```

This still gives the same error (showpoints is NULL).

Comment: I think the main problem in your example is that your `geom_simple_point()` still has the argument showpoints and therefore showpoints is not passed onto `...` and that is why it returns an empty list.

Comment: I thought that as well and removed `showpoints` from `geom_simple_points` completely, but the error stays (argument is of length zero). Also, even if that was the case, (i) I would like to keep the argument explicit in the `geom_simple_points` definition, because it is convenient for users, and (ii) I still don't understand what is happening! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the ways the parameters are being distributed to stats, geoms and positions. If we look at the code of `layer()`:

```
function(arguments){
  ...some_body...
  params <- rename_aes(params)
  aes_params <- params[intersect(names(params), geom$aesthetics())]
  geom_params <- params[intersect(names(params), geom$parameters(TRUE))]
  stat_params <- params[intersect(names(params), stat$parameters(TRUE))]
  all <- c(geom$parameters(TRUE), stat$parameters(TRUE), geom$aesthetics())
  extra_param <- setdiff(names(params), all)
  if (check.param && length(extra_param) > 0) {
    warning("Ignoring unknown parameters: ", paste(extra_param, 
      collapse = ", "), call. = FALSE, immediate. = TRUE)
  }
  ...some_more_body...
}
```

We can see that the parameters you put in `params` (including `...`) are being distributed across the different aspects of a layer based on the names of the params. Anything leftover (`extra_param`) gets discarded and warned about. Since the ellipses `...` is a special case that has no name in and of itself (but the elements in `...` do), this gets discarded if ggplot geoms/stats/aes doesn't know about the elements in `...`.

Now there is an ugly way around this, and that is to make a copy of the ellipses in the very beginning and pass that around as a named argument:

```
geom_simple_point <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
                              position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                              inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  elli <- list(...)
  layer(
    geom = GeomSimplePoint, mapping = mapping,  data = data, stat = stat,
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, elli = elli, ...)
  )   
}
```

Then, we can have the panel drawing function accept this copy of the ellipses as an argument:

```
draw_panel_func <- function(data, panel_params, coord, elli) {
  if(elli$showpoints) {
    coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)
    grid::pointsGrob(coords$x, coords$y)
  } else {
    zeroGrob()
  }
}
```

And update the ggproto accordingly:

```
GeomSimplePoint <- ggproto("GeomSimplePoint", Geom,
                           required_aes = c("x", "y"),
                           default_aes = aes(shape = 19, colour = "black"),
                           draw_key = draw_key_point,
                           extra_params = c("na.rm", "elli"),
                           draw_panel = draw_panel_func
)
```

And now that produces a plot that will work as intended, but it will throw the warning that it is ignoring the `showpoints` parameter because it get's passed to `extra_param` (even though technically it isn't ignored, since it is now part of `elli`). You probably want to code some extra checks in the panel drawing function though, to make sure that `showpoints` was even a provided argument in the beginning.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Yes, it is not the solution I was hoping for, but now I understand what the problem is. Thank you! Also, I can avoid the warning just by packing whatever explicit argument I have in geom_simple_point into `elli`.