# Ellipsis argument documentation

Tags: r, ggplot2

Where can I find a list of all the possible arguments one could use in the ellipsis argument for each Geom/Stat function? In the documentation I only found this:

> "Other arguments passed on to layer(). These are often aesthetics,
>   used to set an aesthetic to a fixed value, like colour = "red" or size
>   = 3. They may also be parameters to the paired geom/stat."

EDIT:

The "layer" documentation is not helpful either:

1) Where are “colour” and “size” there?

2) What can be passed to params (the documentation says “additional parameters to the geom and stat”)?

Comment: I tell you what, this vague documentation really makes me angry too. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57089801/13095326) has some good info on where those `...` arguments actually go.

Comment: What is unclear about "other arguments passed on to layer()"? It's even hyperlinked so you can click on it

Comment: Regarding the layer documentation: 1) Not all arguments there makes sense for all functions (geom inside a geom_rect, for example). 2) Where are “colour” and “size” mentioned in the documentation (quoted in my question)? 3) What can be passed to params (the documentation says “Additional parameters to the geom and stat”)?

Comment: @IanCampbell, thanks for the link. Very interesting! But I'm afraid I'm one step behind: I'm still wondering exactly what those ellipsis are for each method before knowing where and how I could use them.