# custom `geom_` with two different styles for plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

My goal is to write a custom `geom_` method that calculates and plots, e.g., confidence intervals and these should be plotted either as polygons or as lines. The question now is, where to check which "style" should be plotted?

So far I have tried out three different approaches,

- (i) write two different `geom_`/`stat_` for line and polygon style plots,
- (ii) write a  single `geom_`/`stat_` which uses a custom `GeomMethod`,
- (iii) write a single `geom_`/`stat_` which uses either `GeomPolygon` or `GeomLine`.

In my opinion, to sum up

- (i) is more or less straightforward but only bypasses the problem,
- (ii) works when you use either `GeomPath$draw_panel()` or `GeomPolygon$draw_panel()` depending on an extra parameter `style`. But here I can't work it out to set `default_aes` depending also on the extra argument `style`. Compare also the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57075695/6583972).
- (iii) works when calling `geom_` but fails for calling `stat_` as the name matching within **ggplot2** fails. See minimal example below.

Setting up the methods of approach (iii):

```
geom_my_confint <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "my_confint",
                            position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE,
                            show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE,
                            style = c("polygon", "line"), ...) {
  style <- match.arg(style)

  ggplot2::layer(
    geom = if (style == "line") GeomPath else GeomPolygon,
    mapping = mapping,
    data = data,
    stat = stat,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(
      na.rm = na.rm,
      style = style,
      ...
    )
  )
}

stat_my_confint <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "my_confint",
                            position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE,
                            show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE,
                            style = c("polygon", "line"), ...) {

  style <- match.arg(style)

  ggplot2::layer(
    geom = geom, 
    stat = StatMyConfint,
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(
      na.rm = na.rm,
      style = style,
      ...
    )
  )
}

StatMyConfint <- ggplot2::ggproto("StatMyConfint", ggplot2::Stat,
  compute_group = function(data, scales, style) {
    if (style == "polygon") {
      nd <- data.frame(
        x = c(data$x, rev(data$x)),
        y = c(data$y - 1, rev(data$y) + 1)
      )
      nd
    } else {
      nd <- data.frame(
        x = rep(data$x, 2),
        y = c(data$y - 1, data$y + 1),
        group = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5))
      )
      nd
    }
  },
  
  required_aes = c("x", "y")
)
```

Trying out the methods of approach (iii):

```
library("ggplot2")

d <- data.frame(
  x = seq(1, 5),
  y = seq(1, 5)
)

ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + geom_my_confint(style = "polygon", alpha = 0.2)
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + geom_my_confint(style = "line", linetype = 2)
```

This works well so far. However when calling the `stat_` there is an error in `ggplot2:::check_subclass` because there is no `GeomMyConfint` method.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + stat_my_confint()
# Error: Can't find `geom` called 'my_confint'
```

Any solutions or suggestions for alternative approaches?

Answer (score 1):

The following isn't very elegant but seems to work. Let's define the following constructor, wherein the `geom` is set to `GeomMyConfint`, which we'll define further down.

```r
geom_my_confint <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "my_confint",
                            position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE,
                            show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE,
                            style = c("polygon", "line"), ...) {
  style <- match.arg(style)
  
  ggplot2::layer(
    geom = GeomMyConfint,
    mapping = mapping,
    data = data,
    stat = stat,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(
      na.rm = na.rm,
      style = style,
      ...
    )
  )
}
```

Below is the paired ggproto class. I've amended the `use_defaults` method to replace a defaulted colour by some text. Then later, the `draw_panel()` method chooses the actual default to replace the text we've inserted earlier, depending on the `style` argument.

```r
GeomMyConfint <- ggproto(
  "GeomMyConfint", GeomPolygon,

  # Tag colour if it has been defaulted
  use_defaults = function(self, data, params = list(), modifiers = aes()) {
    has_colour <- "colour" %in% names(data) || "colour" %in% names(params)
    data <- ggproto_parent(GeomPolygon, self)$use_defaults(
      data, params, modifiers
    )
    if (!has_colour) {
      data$colour <- "default_colour"
    }
    data
  },

  # Resolve colour defaults here
  draw_panel = function(
    data, panel_params, coord, 
    # Polygon arguments
    rule = "evenodd", 
    # Line arguments
    lineend = "butt", linejoin = "round", linemitre = 10, 
    na.rm = FALSE, arrow = NULL,
    # Switch argument
    style = "polygon") 
  {
    if (style == "polygon") {
      data$colour[data$colour == "default_colour"] <- NA
      GeomPolygon$draw_panel(data, panel_params, coord, rule)
    } else {
      data$colour[data$colour == "default_colour"] <- "black"
      GeomPath$draw_panel(data, panel_params, coord, 
                          arrow, lineend, linejoin, linemitre, na.rm)
    }
  }
)
```

Then then works with the rest of the functions from your example.

A more elegant method might be to use the `vctrs` package to define a custom S3 class for defaulted values that is easy to recognise, but I haven't seen people trying to use `aes(colour = I("default_colour"))` before, so you're probably safe aside from this one single edge case.

Comment: Thanks a lot - it definitely works! But I'm not sure yet if it's too much tweaked and if there might even be a more "ggplot2" conform solution. Or is the approach (i) simply the way to go in **ggplot2**?

Comment: I've extended your answer based on the way `geom_sf()` is implemented. By the way, `geom_sf()` is actually a `geom_*` which can be plotted as point, line, or polygon. So quite similar to my task here.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @teunbrand's answer and how `geom_sf()` is implemented, I came up with the following solution supporting approach (ii):

```
geom_my_confint <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "my_confint",
                            position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE,
                            show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE,
                            type = c("polygon", "line"), ...) {
  type <- match.arg(type)

  ggplot2::layer(
    geom = GeomMyConfint,
    mapping = mapping,
    data = data,
    stat = stat,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(
      na.rm = na.rm,
      type = type,
      ...
    )
  )
}


GeomMyConfint <- ggplot2::ggproto("GeomMyConfint", ggplot2::Geom,

  ## Setting up all defaults needed for `GeomPolygon` and `GeomPath`
  default_aes = ggplot2::aes(
    colour = NA,
    fill = NA,
    size = NA,
    linetype = NA,
    alpha = NA,
    subgroup = NULL
  ),

  draw_panel = function(data, panel_params, coord,
                        rule = "evenodd", # polygon arguments
                        lineend = "butt", linejoin = "round", # line arguments
                        linemitre = 10, na.rm = FALSE, arrow = NULL, # line arguments
                        type = c("polygon", "line")) {
    type <- match.arg(type)

    ## Swap NAs in `default_aes` with own defaults 
    data <- my_modify_list(data, my_default_aesthetics(type), force = FALSE)

    if (type == "polygon") {
      GeomPolygon$draw_panel(data, panel_params, coord, rule)
    } else {
      GeomPath$draw_panel(data, panel_params, coord,
                          arrow, lineend, linejoin, linemitre, na.rm)
    }

  },

  draw_key = function(data, params, size) {
    ## Swap NAs in `default_aes` with own defaults 
    data <- my_modify_list(data, my_default_aesthetics(params$type), force = FALSE)
    if (params$type == "polygon") {
      draw_key_polygon(data, params, size)
    } else {
      draw_key_path(data, params, size)
    }
  }
)


## Helper function inspired by internal from `ggplot2` defined in `performance.R`
my_modify_list <- function(old, new, force = FALSE) {

  if (force) {
    for (i in names(new)) old[[i]] <- new[[i]]
  } else {
    for (i in names(new)) old[[i]] <- if (all(is.na(old[[i]]))) new[[i]] else old[[i]]
  }

  old
}


## Helper function inspired by internal from `ggplot2` defined in `geom-sf.R`
my_default_aesthetics <- function(type) {
  if (type == "line") {
    my_modify_list(GeomPath$default_aes, list(colour = "red", linetype = 2), force = TRUE)
  } else {
    my_modify_list(GeomPolygon$default_aes, list(fill = "red", alpha = 0.2), force = TRUE)
  }
}
```

I've kept the `stat_my_confint()` and `StatMyConfint()` from above unchanged (only the argument `style` is now called `type` according to the naming w/i `geom_sf()`):

```
stat_my_confint <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "my_confint",
                            position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE,
                            show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE,
                            type = c("polygon", "line"), ...) {

  type <- match.arg(type)

  ggplot2::layer(
    geom = geom,
    stat = StatMyConfint,
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(
      na.rm = na.rm,
      type = type,
      ...
    )
  )
}


StatMyConfint <- ggplot2::ggproto("StatMyConfint", ggplot2::Stat,
  compute_group = function(data, scales, type) {
    if (type == "polygon") {
      nd <- data.frame(
        x = c(data$x, rev(data$x)),
        y = c(data$y - 1, rev(data$y) + 1)
      )
      nd
    } else {
      nd <- data.frame(
        x = rep(data$x, 2),
        y = c(data$y - 1, data$y + 1),
        group = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5))
      )
      nd
    }
  },

  required_aes = c("x", "y")
)
```

Now the examples from above work fine:

```
library("ggplot2")

d1 <- data.frame(
  x = seq(1, 5),
  y = seq(1, 5)
)

ggplot(d1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + geom_my_confint()
ggplot(d1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + geom_my_confint(type = "line")
ggplot(d1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + geom_my_confint(type = "polygon", alpha = 0.8)
ggplot(d1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + geom_my_confint(type = "line", linetype = 4, colour = "red")


ggplot(d1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + stat_my_confint()
ggplot(d1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + stat_my_confint(type = "line")
ggplot(d1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + stat_my_confint(type = "polygon", alpha = 0.8)
ggplot(d1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + stat_my_confint(type = "line", linetype = 4, colour = "red")
```

However, the solution still fails if you want additionally, e.g., set the `fill` colour of the polygon by an external grouping variable:

```
d2 <- data.frame(
  x = rep(seq(1, 5), 2),
  y = rep(seq(1, 5), 2),
  z = factor(c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)))
)

ggplot(d2, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + geom_my_confint() + facet_wrap(.~z)
# no error

ggplot(d2, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + geom_line() + geom_my_confint() + facet_wrap(.~z)
# Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_setviewport, vp, TRUE) : 
#  non-finite location and/or size for viewport
```

So still no perfect answer. Help/extensions appreciated!

**EDIT:**

The error no longer occurs if the `size` argument is set to `0.5` within `GeomMyConfint$default_aes()`:

- Not clear to me why - anyone?!
- Here, this works as I don't change the default `size` for `GeomPolygon` or `GeomPath`, but would be problematic otherwise.
- I do not find any more errors (for now).

The adapted code:

```
GeomMyConfint <- ggplot2::ggproto("GeomMyConfint", ggplot2::Geom,

  ## Setting up all defaults needed for `GeomPolygon` and `GeomPath`
  default_aes = ggplot2::aes(
    colour = NA,
    fill = NA,
    size = 0.5,
    linetype = NA,
    alpha = NA,
    subgroup = NULL
  ),
  
  draw_panel = function(data, panel_params, coord,
                        rule = "evenodd", # polygon arguments
                        lineend = "butt", linejoin = "round", # line arguments
                        linemitre = 10, na.rm = FALSE, arrow = NULL, # line arguments
                        type = c("polygon", "line")) {
    type <- match.arg(type)
    
    ## Swap NAs in `default_aes` with own defaults 
    data <- my_modify_list(data, my_default_aesthetics(type), force = FALSE)
    
    if (type == "polygon") {
      GeomPolygon$draw_panel(data, panel_params, coord, rule)
    } else {
      GeomPath$draw_panel(data, panel_params, coord,
                          arrow, lineend, linejoin, linemitre, na.rm)
    }
    
  },
  
  draw_key = function(data, params, size) {
    ## Swap NAs in `default_aes` with own defaults 
    data <- my_modify_list(data, my_default_aesthetics(params$type), force = FALSE)
    if (params$type == "polygon") { 
      draw_key_polygon(data, params, size)
    } else {
      draw_key_path(data, params, size)
    }
  }
)
```

The plot:

```
ggplot(d2, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + geom_line() + geom_my_confint() + facet_wrap(.~z)
```

[image]